# Unity 14.04 Desktop does not take focus for "focus under mouse"

Tags: unity, mouse, focus

I am using an updated 14.04 Ubuntu with Unity (regular setup, nothing fancy or custom). I have "focus under mouse" enabled. This works fine, except that the Desktop cannot get the focus - this is a severe issue as the following shows:

Situation: one window open (e.g. file browser) with the home folder selected (mouse is on this window, it has the focus, all ok). Then, I click on an icon on the desktop screen (i.e. *outside* the browser window). The icon gets selected and seems to have the focus. Then, I hit the [delete] button on the keyboard. Guess what, not the selected icon on the desktop gets deleted but the entire home folder which is selected in the browser window and should *not* have the focus.

Can someone point me to a solution how to get a clean "focus under mouse" behavior?

PS: no worries, I didn't delete the home folder, just a single file when I noted this bad behaviour -- and I could undo the deletion because it just went to the trash.

Comment: I have this problem too, any help available?

Comment: I also have the same problem. Seems like a bug on Unity, but I haven't find a bug report.

Comment: Created a new bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1427636

Comment: The bug was just marked has fixed.

Comment: This bug has not yet been fixed for 14.04 LTS. Just installed a fresh system and had the exact same error. If this bug is indeed fixed, can anyone point me to a ppa or .deb file where I can get the fixed compiz version?